# I cannot generate a single C3.js graph using code samples what might be the issue?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a simple graph, before advancing with the task I copied some of C3's chart samples which i save to an html file and open it with a browser and am ending up with a blank page.

An example of the code am trying to run is:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>d3 | c3 Timeseries Chart test</title>  
    
        <link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.4/c3.min.js"></script>
    
        <style>
            body {font-family: monospace; line-height: 140%; font-size: 18px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class='chart'>
          <div id='chart'></div>
        </div>
    <h4> Chart </h4>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
            var chart = c3.generate({
                data: {
                    x: 'x',
            //        xFormat: '%Y%m%d', // 'xFormat' can be used as custom format of 'x'
                    columns: [
                        ['x', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04', '2014-01-05', '2014-01-06'],
            //            ['x', '20130101', '20130102', '20130103', '20130104', '20130105', '20130106'],
                        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
                        ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
                        ['data3', 70, 220, 200, 100, 600, 512]
                    ]
                },
                axis: {
                    x: {
                        type: 'timeseries',
                        tick: {
                            format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    
            setTimeout(function () {
                chart.load({
                    columns: [
                        ['data4', 400, 500, 450, 700, 600, 100]
                    ]
                });
            }, 1000);
    
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you open the console (f12) what does it say?

Comment: Your code snippet works (somewhat) on my browser, what browser and version are you using? Have you tried it on different browsers? Do you get the same problem on all of them?

Comment: @Bardo chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit)

Comment: @Bálint c3 not defined, weird though cause am linking to a cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Because C3.js is probably a huge file, downloading it takes a considerable amount of time. Meanwhile the browser runs your script, but because the file is still in a downloading state, c3 won't be defined.

To fix this, you have multiple options:

a) Put your script in a different file and add the defer tag to the script tag:

```
<script src="yourscript.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

b) Put your code in the window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // Your script goes here
}
```